# Compiling project with 'provided' dependencies

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak

I've a task to extend/change authorization flow using keycloak and probably found some information about it on (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi).

First thing what I wanted to do was creating simple project which could let my run on wildfly server. But when I added some dependencies to pom.xml I cannot provide dependencies which should be already there (by provide scope in maven project). How can I provide it? 
I downloaded keycloak from official site and run in standalone mode by standalone.sh file in bin directory.

I'm just prepare pom.xml from some tutorial and it looks like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>spi-custom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Custom Saml Mapper</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-parent</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-saml-core-public</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>adam-saml-group-mapper</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Running command `mvn clean install widlfy:deploy` display error message:

```
Failed to execute goal on project spi-custom: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.examples:spi-custom:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi-private:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.keycloak:keycloak-services:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
org.keycloak:keycloak-saml-core-public:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
Xould not find artifact org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

One dependency was founded (jboss-logging) but any other couldn't be resolved.

Comment: Those version numbers don't seem right. Fix the Keycloak version number and it should be able to download them.

Comment: You are right, when version was deleted dependecies were found.  But there is another problem with maven-plugin. It's look like wildfly:deploy goal throw exception with:
```Could not find artifact sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk at specified path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/../lib/jconsole.jar```

Comment: Consider using keycloak and wildfly BOMs when you develop customized SPI.